# OpenCv webcam reading official code is very slow

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, webcam

I just got a highend 1080p webcam, opening it in the "camera" app of windows 10 display it flawlessly, at 25 or 30fps, however when using opencv it's very laggy, I put a timer in the loop while disabling the display and I have around 200ms between each frame.

Why?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

def getAvailableCameraIds(max_to_test):
    available_ids = []
    for i in range(max_to_test):
        temp_camera = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
        if temp_camera.isOpened():
            temp_camera.release()
            print "found camera with id {}".format(i)
            available_ids.append(i)
    return available_ids

def displayCameraFeed(cameraId, width, height):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cameraId)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

    while(True):
        start = time.time()
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        end = time.time()
        print "time to read a frame : {} seconds".format(end-start)

        #DISABLED
        #cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        #if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            #break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#print getAvailableCameraIds(100)
displayCameraFeed(0, 1920, 1080)
```

Thanks

Opencv 3.1 on a windows 10 x64, with python 2.7 x64

Comment: What CPU does your system have? Python runs in an interpreter and thus is much slower than compiled code like what windows webcam viewer will have.

Comment: i7 4720HQ@2.6Ghz

Comment: I would suspect it is to do with the fact it is being run on python, this article might be able to help you: [Faster video file FPS with cv2.VideoCapture and OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/06/faster-video-file-fps-with-cv2-videocapture-and-opencv/)

Comment: allright, tomorow I will try it on my desktop which has a more powerful hardware and I will try it in C++

Comment: OpenCV is a python-wrapped C++ library, so the gains might not be huge. Either way, threading and queues are recommended so that the program can make full use of your computer's resources (like multiple cores if it has them).

Comment: @Totoro : I don't see how threading here would help, the atomic operation '.read()' takes 200ms

Comment: Right, your code just reads images and there is no processing involved. But that is unusually slow; I get more than 10 frames on a Linux box with roughly that much CPU power. Is OpenCV on Windows pre-compiled? It might not be optimized to your machine. You can verify that if you try the C++ version.

Answer (score 4):

for me this did the trick on Windows 10 with a Logitech c922.
The order in which the methods a called seem to have an impact.
(i have 'import cv' instead of 'import cv2')

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture(camera_index + cv.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'))
```

Comment: cv.CAP_DSHOW is enough in my case. cap.set's are unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same problem on my linux system where I had 150ms delay between frames. In my case, the problem was that the Auto Exposure feature of the camera was ON, which increased exposure times, causing the delay.

Turning OFF auto exposure reduced delay to 49~51 ms

Here is a link from OBSProject that talks about it https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/getting-the-most-out-of-your-webcam.1036/

I'm not sure how you'd do this on a windows machine, a Google search revealed that changing it on your Skype settings changes it globally. (If you have bundled software with your camera, you could probably change it there as well.)

As for a linux machine, running `v4l2-ctl --list-ctrls` lists the features of your camera that you can modify.

I set `exposure_auto_priority (bool)` to `0` which turns OFF Auto Exposure.